# convert string to float in a loop

Tags: python, parsing

I don't really understand why it does not work. Can someone help me?

I have a text file in which data is listed like this.

04/05/2015 15:30    58.6

04/05/2015 16:00    56.3

...

each line has 3 space separated data.

I read with

```
with open('./data') as fi:

    data = [[t for t in line.split() ]for line in fi]
```

Then the variable has the data

```
[['04/05/2015', '15:30', '58.6'],
 ['04/05/2015', '16:00', '56.3'],
...
]
```

I'd like to take out only the data in the 3rd column, then I made a loop.

```
for t in data:
    a=float(t[2])
```

But I got an error

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call      last)
<ipython-input-76-83c96b309de0> in <module>()
      2 i=0
      3 for t in data:
----> 4     a=float(t[2])
      5 

ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

What I don't understand is if I replace 'a=' with 'print ', it printed the values.

```
for t in data:
    print float(t[2])
```

Why it does not work by substitution but printing values?

Comment: Can you specify the value of `t[2]` when the error occurs?

Comment: Show us the full contents of the file.

Comment: Additionally, the nested comprehension is pointless. Use: `[line.split() for line in fi]`

Comment: I looked into the data. There was '\xc2\xa0'...

Comment: It looks like you have a Unicode file, encoded using UTF-8. So you should specify that encoding when you open the file. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codecs.open

Comment: Also see [Unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html). Note that Unicode handling in Python 3 is rather better than how it works in Python 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have unicode characters in your input file. You can specify the encoding with which you open your file with [codecs.open](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codecs.open):

```
import codecs
with codecs.open("input.txt", encoding="utf-8") as f:
  data = [line.split() for line in f]
a = []
for row in data:
  print [col for col in row]
for t in data:
  try:
    a.append(float(t[2]))
  except ValueError:
    break
print(a)
```

The above prints `[58.6, 56.3]` with

```
04/05/2015 15:30 58.6
04/05/2015 16:00 56.3
04/05/2015 16:00 \xc2\xa0
```

in `input.txt`.

Comment: I am sorry for my stupidness. The data has a string which is not value at all. That was why I got the error.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show how you can open a file with utf8 encoding.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Even though the problem was just my overlooking but your answer helped me a lot for my work.